# Adding in two elements in eloquent db with circular foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, circular-reference

Hi I was wondering how I could create two elements whom's foreign keys form a circular structure in eloquent php (laravel).
I have two tables, persons and actions these are there structures (mock up) :

**persons :**

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint auto increment |
| name | varchar(255) |
| last_action_id | bigint |

**Foreign key :**
last_action_id → actions(id)

**actions :**

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint auto increment |
| description | varchar(255) |
| person_id | bigint |

**Foreign key :**
person_id → persons(id)

I would like to create a new person and his/her first action.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you've not given a massive amount of information, I don't see why you would need to do it this way. Each person has many actions, presumably, so set up the relationships accordingly :

In your Person model :

```
public function actions() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Action::class);
}
```

In your Action model :

```
public function person() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

Then to retrieve their last action you could just instantiate your person, get their actions, then retrieve the last of those using :

```
$person->actions->last();
```

Comment: builders/relationships don't have a `last` method ... i am assuming you want to call that on the Collection `$person->actions->last()` or directly on the builder to only return 1 result `$person->actions()->latest('id')->first()`

Comment: Yes, fair point (was late for me when I wrote the answer) - have edited it.